# Possible bug in snippets

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

In my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637739/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-null-at-window-onload/43637898#43637898) the return of `document.getElementsByTagName()` is incorrect.

As far as I can tell, this is caused by the way the window.onload() is being dealt with.

Minimal reproduction of issue:

```html
<script>
    var a=8
    window.onload=function(){
         console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('div').length)
    }
</script>
```

Note to help debugging: if you add another script tag **with contents** this will give you a new phantom 'div'.

Comment: Why are you including the script in the HTML section, rather than the JavaScript section?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan because of the way it was written in the question- (note what I wrote at the bottom of my answer there.)

Comment: Even if the script is in the proper section, it still gives the same 2 result with the code as written.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here in *console*.

If you open devtools, you can see, that *console* is just simple div, and if you *disable* console in snippet all would be correct.

```html
<script>
  var a = 8
  window.onload = function() {
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('div').length)
  }
</script>
```

In browser console you can see right answer - 0.

Alternative way for fixing is find divs *inside* some container, for example:

```html
<script>
  var a = 8
  window.onload = function() {
    console.log(document.querySelector('.container').getElementsByTagName('div').length)
  }
</script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: this will only work if you know there is a problem- if a question or answer is posted by someone not knowing about this the snippet could easily  display incorrect behaviour if using indexing on the array returned, for example.